# Disable Auth Register route in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need to disable my register route in Laravel 8. Tried

```
Auth::routes([
     'register' => false,
     'login' => false,
]);
```

but the application threw up an error.

```
RuntimeException
In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.
```

If anyone points out what needs to change, will be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: run `composer require laravel/ui`

Comment: Have already done that. My auth functionality is running fine.

Comment: `Auth::routes([]);` is a method of `laravel/ui`, which is not available in laravel 8 jetstream

Comment: then run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: On `fortify.php` under `features` property comment out or delete this line `Features::registration(),`

Comment: People can't login without an account, so just disable the register feature in `config/fortify.php`. The `laravel/ui` package is designed for Laravel 6 and 7 -- it can be installed with Laravel 8 too, but the "new thing" there is Jetstream for your authentication scaffolding.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Laravel 8 uses **fortify** authentication. To disable registration from your laravel app, you need to disable it from **fortify**, which is located on `/config/fortify.php`

```
'features' => [
    // Features::registration(), // disable here
     Features::resetPasswords(),
     Features::emailVerification(),
     Features::updateProfileInformation(),
     Features::updatePasswords(),
     Features::twoFactorAuthentication(),
],
```

Comment: Hello good sir, how about making the path "login"  unavailable too? Your answer helped me on the "/register" path, but by trying the same approach to the "login" path it throws me QueryExceptionError, hope to hear from you! Cheers.

Comment: I have Laravel 8.x and no config/fortify.php class. Nor that array.

Comment: @LaynierPiedra You have to publish it. Presumably you did this to create the Fortify service provider and migration, no? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#installation

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"`

`Copied File [/vendor/laravel/fortify/stubs/fortify.php] To [/config/fortify.php]`

`Copied File [/vendor/laravel/fortify/stubs/FortifyServiceProvider.php] To [/app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php]`

`Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/fortify/database/migrations] To [/database/migrations]`

`Publishing complete.`

Comment: I did not installed Fortify

Comment: how to disable logout feature?

Comment: This is the correct way to use Laravel.

Answer (score 12):

At the end of my `routes/web.php` was the following line:

```
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

In `routes/auth.php` are listed all additional routes for user login/register/logout. Just comment out or remove `/register` route from there.

Comment: this should be the corrent answer

Answer (score 8):

In addition, be sure to disable related routes, in `routes/web.php` :

```php
Route::get('/register', function() {
    return redirect('/login');
});

Route::post('/register', function() {
    return redirect('/login');
});
```

I changed according feature tests in `tests/Feature/RegistrationTest.php` to try to keep work clean so I needed those redirections.

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the registration routes from **config/auth.php** and then create a **config/fortify.php** (paste the content from: **vendor/laravel/fortify/config/fortify.php**) which will override the default settings.

Inside **config/fortify.php** comment out the first element of features array (**Features::registration()**) then run **php artisan optimize** to clear config cache and routes cache.

Now all your removed routes should return 404, you can also check if those still exist with **php artisan route:list**

config/fortify.php:

```
<?php

use Laravel\Fortify\Features;

return [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'middleware' => ['web'],
    'passwords' => 'users',
    'username' => 'email',
    'email' => 'email',
    'views' => true,
    'home' => '/home',
    'prefix' => '',
    'domain' => null,
    'limiters' => [
        'login' => null,
    ],
    'features' => [
        //Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication(),
    ],
];
```

Comment: the `vendor/laravel/fortify` does not exist in my `laravel 8`

Answer (score 1):

Do not break your head with different versions of packages and Laravel. Because maybe you don't have fortify.php in your config, or using different packages. All routes are in routes/web now. Just go there and force that '/register' sends to login or any other view you want to:

```
Route::any('/register', function() {
    return  view('auth.login');
});
```

That way you maintain out of reach that feature, but close for when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

If the changes still don't reflect, clear the route:cache by doing as below:

```
PHP artisan ro:cache
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put this in your `/routes/web.php`:

```
Route::any('/register', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);
```